# Autodesk Maya, C++ and OpenGL rendering engine

Tags: c++, opengl, maya

1. What graphics engine Maya uses, OpenGL or DirectX? Does it at all use any? Since maya is written in C++.
2. For going deep into Maya, is it proper to learn to use OpenGL or one should go with DirectX?
3. My questions specially are associated with adding super new functionalities, such as new edge-system for a certain geometry in Maya.

Comment: A `>` character at the beginning of a line denotes a block quote. Please bear that in mind for the future. Consider using numbered/bullet lists as you can see in [my edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/25398270/revisions)

Comment: thanks for noting Bojangles

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What graphics engine Maya uses

Its own.

Neither OpenGL nor Direct3D are graphics *engines*. They're drawing APIs. You push in bunches of data and parameters and shaders to make sense of that data, and rasterized points, lines and triangles on a 2D framebuffer come out on the other side. That's it.

Maya, like every other graphics program out there implements its own engine or uses a graphics engine library that maybe uses Direct3D or OpenGL as a backend. In the case of Maya OpenGL is used for the interactive display. But the offline renderer is independent from that.

> For going deep into Maya, is it proper to learn to use OpenGL or one should go with DirectX?

As long as you don't want to write lower-level-ish Maya plug-ins, you don't have to learn either.

> My questions specially are associayted with adding super new functionalities, such as new edge-system for a certain geometry in Maya.

You surely want to make that available to the offline renderer as well. As such neiter OpenGL nor Direct3D are of use for you. You have to implement this using the graphics pipeline functions offered by Maya and its renderer. Note that you might also have to patch into external renderers if you want to use those with your news edge features.

Comment: thanks much. But openGL is low-level enough to enable you write advanced simulations?(I know there a lot of maths and physics required)

Comment: @MostafaTalebi: OpenGL doesn't deal with simulating stuff. It just draws things. Nothing more. Of course you can use OpenGL as a visualization backend for some simulation system (just have a look at the example code for the Bullet Physics library for an example). But it's not OpenGL doing the simulating. OpenGL is to a simulation what a pen is to a writer of literature.

Comment: @MostafaTalebi: If you're thinking about simulating the physics of real world illumination (i.e. physically based rendering), then yes, you can do that using OpenGL; but then it's more like the skillfull use of brushes and technique to draw a photorealistic painting on a physical canvas.

Comment: Oh I knew that, I went a little careless. I know it has noting to with simulation, I meant the same drawing staff of simulation which differ from those of simple rendering.

Comment: You can do open GL drawing in maya using the API, but if you have very hard core requirements (like dense data or high framerates) you might want to consider [Fabric Engine](http://fabricengine.com/) which is better suited for heavy duty display applications inside of Maya.